# How to render nested innerHtml element into innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, innerhtml

I have a `div` which renders HTML code currency:

```
<div [innerHtml]="item.Currency" title="" class="currTooltip"> <!-- This div 
                                            renders and show currency! -->  

    <div [innerHtml]="item.Currency" title="" class="tooltiptext"></div> <!-- This div
                                                          never rendered! -->   
</div>
```

`item.Currency` is equal to `&#165;`

What it is possible to see in `DOM`:

[image]

However, inside `div` never renders. What can I do to render inside `div`
where there is a comment `<!-- This div never rendered! -->`?

Comment: Change `innerHtml` for `innerHTML`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks, nevertheless it does not render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to set the content of the outer div in two different ways at the same time. You include an inner div as its content and you also specify its `innerHTML` property. Only one of the two will be used (the one set with `innerHTML`, apparently). You should decide if the outer div contains the inner div, or if its content is provided by `innerHTML`.

If you want to have both, you can use one of these methods:

**Method 1** - Include two inner elements:

```
<div title="" class="currTooltip">
  <span [innerHTML]="item.Currency" ></span>
  <div [innerHtml]="item.Currency" title="" class="tooltiptext"></div>
</div>
```

**Method 2** - Include the entire inner div HTML inside of the `innerHTML` property of the outer div:

```
<div [innerHTML]="item.Currency + innerDivHtml" title="" class="currTooltip">
</div>
```

with `innerDivHtml` defined as a property getter:

```
get innerDivHtml(): string {
  return `<div title="" class="tooltiptext">${this.item.Currency}</div>`;
}
```

Comment: please, see my updated question. I am so sorry for misleading you by conditions of task. I just wanted to simplify condition of task. Please, see my question again.

Comment: In any case, you cannot include the inner div inside of the outer one, and set `innerHTML` of the outer div at the same time, and expect to see both content.